# Liferay - catching action phase to set 'waiting' cursor

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, liferay

I'm working on big liferay project and I have the following problem :

everytime when something is loading, processing etc. I should change cursor to waiting gif. It's easy when using Ajax, but in many cases here I don't use it. So I thought maybe if I could catch any action phase I'd somehow set cursor to wait at the beginning of action method and then turn back to regular 'auto' at the end.

Is that possible ? I don't like this 'solution' but I can't think of any better. Currently I have div with loading image in my jsp which is then removed by jquery document.ready() - not satisfied at all, because all the proccessing have been performed earlier in action phase.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are not using Ajax, it might be difficult to achieve what you are looking for.

You could start showing the throbber ("loading image") once the link on the first page is clicked, keep it on the next page and remove it on document.ready().

But you'll still have a few ms or seconds without throbber, during page load.

If the processing time is really long, you could do the following :
The idea is to use a thread for the processing. A reference to the thread is stored in server's session. When the link is clicked :

- Display a page with the loading image and start the processing in the thread
- Poll the server every X second to check if the thread (in session !) is done
- When the thread is done, display the result.

Comment: I've came up with very similar idea while waiting for sb's response :) thank you anyway, works just fine